# Map multiple address with users json react js

Tags: json, reactjs

I'm trying to build ReactJS API where I have 2 JSON files.

- The 1st file contains all the users
- 2nd file contains all the address of the user.

Here's a snippet of both of the JSON.

`Users.json`

```
{
  "User": [
    {
      "BossId": "3",
      "DateOfBirth": "1966-09-27T00:00:00",
      "FamilyName": "Montejano",
      "Gender": "Unspecified",
      "GivenName": "Trinh",
      "Id": "8",
      "Title": "Tech Manager"
    },
    {
      "BossId": null,
      "DateOfBirth": "1927-01-29T00:00:00",
      "FamilyName": "Fetzer",
      "Gender": "Unspecified",
      "GivenName": "Winfred",
      "Id": "1",
      "Title": "CEO"
    },
]
}
```

Address.json

```
{
  "StreetAddress": [
    {
      "Id": 1,
      "PersonId": 1,
      "Street": "62 Durham Court",
      "City": "Garfield",
      "State": "NJ",
      "Zip": "07026"
    },
    {
      "Id": 2,
      "PersonId": 1,
      "Street": "179 Cambridge Court",
      "City": "Chippewa Falls",
      "State": "WI",
      "Zip": "54729"
    },
  ]
}
```

How can I map Users with their addresses?

This is the current way I'm doing it as suggested in answers.

```
import React from "react";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      users: [],
      adresses: []
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    import("./data/PersonData").then(users => {
      this.setState({ users });
    });
    import("./data/StreetAddress").then(adresses => {
      this.setState({ adresses });
    });

    const result = this.state.users.map(user => ({
      ...user,
      adresses: this.state.adresses.filter(adr => adr.PersonId === user.Id)
    }));
    console.log(result);
  }
  render() {

    return <div className="App"></div>;
  }
}

export default App;
```

and I'm getting an empty array in the console. and this is the output I'm looking for

```
{
    "User": {
        "Id" : "1",
        "FirstName" : "Winfred",
        "LastName" : "Fetzer",
        "BossName" : null,
        "Title" : "CEO",
        "DateOfBirth" : "1927-01-29",
        "Gender" : "Female",
        "Addresses" : [{
            "Id" : 1,
            "Street" :  "62 Durham Court",
            "City" : "Garfield",
            "State" : "NJ",
            "Zip" : "07026"
        },{
            "Id" : 2,
            "Street" :  "179 Cambridge Court",
            "City" : "Chippewa Falls",
            "State" : "WI",
            "Zip" : "54729"
        },{
            "Id" : 3,
            "Street" :  "573 Route 5",
            "City" : "Memphis",
            "State" : "TN",
            "ZipCode" : "38106"
        }]
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your desired final JSON ?

Comment: @Treycos I have updated the question with desired output

Comment: I updated my answer to fit your ouput

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could map it the following way :

```js
const adresses =  [
    {
        "Id": 1,
        "PersonId": 1,
        "Street": "62 Durham Court",
        "City": "Garfield",
        "State": "NJ",
        "Zip": "07026"
    },
    {
        "Id": 2,
        "PersonId": 1,
        "Street": "179 Cambridge Court",
        "City": "Chippewa Falls",
        "State": "WI",
        "Zip": "54729"
    },
]

const users = [
    {
        "BossId": "3",
        "DateOfBirth": "1966-09-27T00:00:00",
        "FamilyName": "Montejano",
        "Gender": "Unspecified",
        "GivenName": "Trinh",
        "Id": "8",
        "Title": "Tech Manager"
    },
    {
        "BossId": null,
        "DateOfBirth": "1927-01-29T00:00:00",
        "FamilyName": "Fetzer",
        "Gender": "Unspecified",
        "GivenName": "Winfred",
        "Id": "1",
        "Title": "CEO"
    },
]

const result = {
    Users: users.map(user => ({
        ...user,
        adresses: adresses.filter(adr => adr.PersonId == user.Id).map(({ PersonId, ...rest }) => rest)
    }))
}

console.log(result)
```

It seems like your adresses ids are numbers and that your person's id are string, which is why I used the `==` operator

**EDIT:**

The above approach is good if there are potentially multiple addresses per user. `addresses.filter(..)` will create a new array containing all addresses with the person's ID.

If you only ever expect one address per person you would want to use `addresses.find(...)` instead.

```
const result = users.map(user => ({
    ...user,
    adresses: adresses.find(adr => adr.PersonId == user.Id)
}))
```

---

You are receiving an empty array because you are **not** waiting for your data to be loaded :

```
    import("./data/PersonData").then(users => {
      this.setState({ users });
    });
```

Doing this will not wait for your file to be imported, even if your variable is in the state, the only function that will be called another time is `render`, where your variable will now be accessible. You have 3 ways to solve this problem :

1 - Awaiting your imports, although it may be considered bad practice :

```
componentDidMount = async() {
    const users = await import("./data/PersonData")
    const adresses = await import("./data/StreetAddress")

    const result = users.map(user => ({
      ...user,
      adresses: adresses.filter(adr => adr.PersonId === user.Id)
    }));
    console.log(result);
}
```

2 - Import your files at the beggining of your class :

```
import React from "react";
import users from "./data/PersonData.json"
import adresses from "./data/StreetAddress.json"

class App extends React.Component {
```

3 - Use your data in your render function :

```
componentDidMount() {
    import("./data/PersonData").then(users => {
      this.setState({ users });
    });
    import("./data/StreetAddress").then(adresses => {
      this.setState({ adresses });
    });
  }

  render() {
    const result = this.state.users.map(user => ({
      ...user,
      adresses: this.state.adresses.filter(adr => adr.PersonId === user.Id)
    }));
    console.log(result);
    return <div className="App"></div>;
  }
```

In your case, I think the second solution is more suited for your needs

Now, the new mapping :

```
const result = {
    Users: users.map(user => ({
        ...user,
        adresses: adresses.filter(adr => adr.PersonId == user.Id).map(({ PersonId, ...rest }) => rest)
    }))
}
```

Now your `PersonId` will not be included in the address

Comment: Question: How can I do it with Class based component?

Comment: By simply wrapping it in a class, this code will work the same way anywhere, can you be more precise ?

Comment: yes sure, once I try this solution I'll update the question with desired JSON as well

Comment: Updated the question as output needed

Comment: Your edit(s) are extensively helpful but I'm getting `.map()` is not a function, trying to figure out where I'm going wrong

Comment: An import failure would make an error at `.filter`, but there I don't see how filter could not return an array... Can you try printing the content of the files you imported right before using them ?

Comment: All it prints is TypeError and an empty array in console: `TypeError: _data_PersonData_json__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_8__.map is not a function`

Comment: Can you expand you orignal answer based on suggestion 3?

Comment: Try re-using the second one I'm editing it since I made a typo

Comment: The import syntax doesnt require `()` and I forgot to add the file extension

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185447/discussion-between-yash-karanke-and-treycos).

Answer (score 0):

Simply map the `User`'s `Id` to the `StreetAddress`'s `PersonId`:

```js
const usersJson = {
  "User": [
    {
      "BossId": "3",
      "DateOfBirth": "1966-09-27T00:00:00",
      "FamilyName": "Montejano",
      "Gender": "Unspecified",
      "GivenName": "Trinh",
      "Id": "8",
      "Title": "Tech Manager"
    },
    {
      "BossId": null,
      "DateOfBirth": "1927-01-29T00:00:00",
      "FamilyName": "Fetzer",
      "Gender": "Unspecified",
      "GivenName": "Winfred",
      "Id": "1",
      "Title": "CEO"
    },
]
}

const addressesJson = {
  "StreetAddress": [
    {
      "Id": 1,
      "PersonId": 1,
      "Street": "62 Durham Court",
      "City": "Garfield",
      "State": "NJ",
      "Zip": "07026"
    },
    {
      "Id": 2,
      "PersonId": 1,
      "Street": "179 Cambridge Court",
      "City": "Chippewa Falls",
      "State": "WI",
      "Zip": "54729"
    },
  ]
}

const users = usersJson["User"]
const addresses = addressesJson["StreetAddress"]
const usersWithAddresses = users.map(user => {
 user.Addresses = addresses.find(a => a["PersonId"] == user["Id"])
  return user
})

usersWithAddresses.forEach(u => {
 document.getElementById("root").innerHTML += JSON.stringify(u)
})
```

```html
<div id="root">

</div>
```